# Comparing floats by ignoring last bit in golang

Tags: go, floating-point

A specification reads as follows:

> It still considers real numbers equal if they differ in their last
>   binary digit.

I would like to implement this way of comparing floats for the float64 data type in Go. Unfortunately, the bitwise operators aren't defined for floating point numbers. Is there a way to achieve this way of comparing floats in the Go language?

Comment: What is the "last binary digit" of a real number? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @PaulHankin I am trying to replicate the behavior of another system and that is the only description I have of how that system handles comparisons. But in my test case your `almostEqual` gives the same result, I will accept it in a while after others have had a chance to respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if two `float64` values are adjacent (that is, there's no `float64` value between them):

```
func almostEqual(a, b float64) bool {
    ai, bi := int64(math.Float64bits(a)), int64(math.Float64bits(b))
    return a == b || -1 <= ai-bi && ai-bi <= 1
}
```

Mostly that's the same as saying they differ in the lowest bit of their mantissa.

This code doesn't work if `a` or `b` are NaNs, zeros or infinities, but you could add special cases if you wished.

See https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a perfect use case for the following function from the math package:

```
func equal(x, y float64) bool {
    return math.Nextafter(x, y) == y
}
```

> Nextafter returns the next representable float64 value after x towards y.
>   
> Special cases are:
>   
> Nextafter(x, x)   = x
>   
> Nextafter(NaN, y) = NaN
>   
> Nextafter(x, NaN) = NaN

https://play.golang.org/p/unRkkoe6wb